# Order of an element divides $m$ when $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

https://brilliant.org/wiki/order-of-an-element/

I was referring to the above link for order of an element and in basic properties while proving property $1$ due to minimality of d, $d \le gcd(m,d)$ is written.

Is it because $mx+dy\ge d$ i.e. $gcd(m,d)\ge d$ but that inequality hold only for all positive $x$ and $y$ but there are cases when $x$ is positive and $y$ is negative, in that case $mx+dy \le d$ ie $gcd(m,d)\le d$?

Can someone help me what does the minimality of d actually mean and how did this inequality obtained $d \le gcd(m,d)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is defined to be the **smallest** positive $p$ such that $a^p \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ holds.

Since we have shown that $a^{gcd(d.m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ and we know that $gcd(d,m)>0$, then we must have $d \le gcd(d,m)$.

Comment: In the same post it is given $a^(mx+ny) \equiv 1\pmod n$ for all x and y but in cases where either x is negative  $a^m \equiv 1\pmod n$ $a^(mx) $ can't equal to 1\pmod n$ ?

Comment: Are you asking if $x$ can be negative? Yes, it can. Note taht $a$ and $n$ are coprime and the inverse exists.

Comment: For example 3^6 = 1 mod 7 but if x=-1 3^(6*-1) can't be equal to 1 mod 7?

Comment: If $3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, multiply $3^{-6} $ on both sides and we get $1 \equiv 3^{-6} \pmod{7}$.

Comment: If $3^x \equiv 2\pmod 7$ then x is of the form 6k+2 does k belong to Z ie k can take negative values also?

Comment: yes it can. $3^{6k+2} \equiv (3^6)^k\cdot 3^2 \equiv 1^k \cdot 2 \equiv 2$, it works regardless of the sign of $k$.

Comment: $3^{-6}$ equals 0.00137 what does actually a decimal value mod 7 mean because $3^{-6} \equiv 1\pmod n$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109855/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-bhanu-sri).